# scanf not reading the whole string

Tags: c, pointers

I was writing a program in C for lexicographically sorting the strings entered by user , but whenever i am entering a string with string length greater than 3 my code shows some garbage values and i am not able to understand why ?
My line of Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void lexiiographic_sort(char** , int );
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    char** arr;
    arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if ((*(arr + i) = (char*)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char))) == NULL) { exit(1); }
        scanf_s("%s", *(arr + i),sizeof(*(arr + i)));
        if ((*(arr + i) = (char*)realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1)) == NULL) { exit(1); }
        printf("%s\n", *(arr + i));
    }
    lexiiographic_sort(arr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *(arr + i));
    }
}
void lexiiographic_sort(char** string, int size)
{
    char* temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if ((int)(*(*(string + j - 1))) > (int)(*(*(string + j))))
            {
                if ((temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(*(string + i - 1)) * sizeof(char) + 1)) == NULL) { exit(1); }
                temp = *(string + j - 1);
                if((temp = ((char*)realloc(temp, strlen(*(string + j)) * sizeof(char) + 1))) == NULL){exit(1); }
                *(string + j - 1) = *(string + j);
                *(string + j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: better to add how this `scanf_s` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get size of dynamically allocated buffer via `sizeof`. `sizeof(*(arr + i))` is the size of a pointer `char*`. It seems it is 4 in your environment and it is the reason of the 3-character limit (one is left for terminating null-character).

You used the hard-coded number `1024` as the buffer size, so use that instead.

```
        scanf_s("%s", *(arr + i),1024);
```

Defining a macro for buffer size and using them will improve your code more.

Comment: Ohh Yes ! , that was indeed a very small one but turned out to big mistake , i mistakenly forgot that i am passing the size of pointer not the string , Thanks a lot